# Struts 2 - Pre-populate a form using the Object's Attributes

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to pre-populate a form using `Struts 2` tags with the values of attributes of the object that I have received from session.

```
PromoCode promoCode = (PromoCode) session.getAttribute("PROMOCODE");
```

I tried with this approach but it did not work.

```jsp
<s:form action="add">
            <s:select label="Ticket Name " name="ticketName" list="{'PARTY PLATINUM', 'INAUGURATION PREMIUM'}"></s:select>
            <s:textfield label="Promotion Type " value="%{promoCode.promotionType}" name="promotionType"></s:textfield>
            <s:select label="Discount Access " value="promoCode.discountAccess" name="discountAccess" list="{'Choose Your Discount Access', 'Coded Discount', 'Public Discount'}"></s:select>
            <s:textfield label="Name of the Public Discount " name="nameOfPublicDiscount"></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield label="Discount per ticket (%) " value="promoCode.discountPerTicket" name="discountPerTicket"></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield label="Uses per offer " value="promoCode.uses" name="uses"></s:textfield>
            <br/>
            <s:submit id="update" value="UPDATE"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Put a getter for promoCode :o)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `promoCode` class variable with getter and setter. In Struts2 to get http session attributes you should use a session map that is injected to your action bean via interceptor which intercepts `SessionAware` interface.

```java
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

  private PromoCode promoCode;
  public PromoCode getPromoCode(){ return promoCode; }
  public void setPromoCode(PromoCode promoCode){ this.promoode = promoCode; }
  private Map<String, Object> session;

  @Override
  public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
   this.session = session;
  } 
  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    PromoCode promoCode = (PromoCode) session.get("PROMOCODE");
    setPromoCode(promoCode);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

---

In the JSP you should bind input fields to action bean properties.

```jsp
<s:form action="add">
    <s:select label="Ticket Name " name="promoCode.ticketName" list="{'PARTY PLATINUM', 'INAUGURATION PREMIUM'}"></s:select>
    <s:textfield label="Promotion Type "  name="promoCode.promotionType"></s:textfield>
    <s:select label="Discount Access "  name="promoCode.discountAccess" list="{'Choose Your Discount Access', 'Coded Discount', 'Public Discount'}"></s:select>
    <s:textfield label="Name of the Public Discount " name="promoCode.nameOfPublicDiscount"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield label="Discount per ticket (%) "  name="promoCode.discountPerTicket"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield label="Uses per offer " name="promoCode.uses"></s:textfield>
    <br/>
    <s:submit id="update" value="UPDATE"/>
</s:form>
```

---